# What objects are supported in threejs JSON format?

Tags: json, three.js

I'm trying to export a scene from some modeling software to `three.js` using the latest JSON format (4).

It's not clear what objects are supported in this format.

Are mesh files (.stl, .obj), AxisHelper, ArrowHelper and TextGeometry supported?

I *can* export mesh files using Geometry but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

What objects are supported?

Comment: you can find some related info in http://threejs.org/docs/ (loaders section).

Comment: Thanks @mlkn I checked that earlier and it had no details in the docs, but browsing thru the code on github shows that TextGeometry is supported and the rest are not, though it's not clear why.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the code it looks like that supported "objects" in the JSON format are:

- Geometry
- Material
- Skinning/Bones
- Animation/Frames
- Morphing
- Lights
- Cameras

So AxisHelper, ArrowHelper and TextGeometry is not.